# Doxygen class/fuction names in graphs

Tags: class, inheritance, graph, namespaces, doxygen

I run Doxygen with class-graph, I got this graph [Inheritance graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9o8t.png)

can anyone explain what does :: mean in the org:apache::Cassandra::utils::ICachable<K,V>

Answer (score 0):

:: is a scope resolution operator generally used when you have to be explicit about what you're referring to. Here an example:

```
struct Base {
    void foo();
};
struct Derived : Base {
    void foo();
    void bar() {
       Derived::foo();
       Base::foo();
    }
};
```

In this example, you can specify which foo() function is being called.

If you need some help with graphs legend, check this [link](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/diagrams/html/graph_legend.html) that could be helpful to you.

Comment: I'm building a software network where the nodes are classes and the edges are the relationships. So basically  org::apache::Cassandra::utils::ICachable<K,V> is the same as org.apache.Cassandra.utils.ICachable<K,V>